# How to play audio file recorded via Media Recorder in a browser?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am using android Media Recorder to  record audio .Code works fine .Audio is getting recorded and played successfully in a device. I am setting output format  for audio file as THREE_GPP and Audio encoder as DEFAULT.These files are not getting played in a browser and  which is my actual requirement.I think SetAudioEncoder is giving me problem .
I have tried setting another encoder which is  AMR_NB , but still the same problem.I have installed flash player, but no luck. I am using android-sdk 8.
Is there any way with i can play my files in a browser .

Any help will do. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 _recorder.Reset();
                _recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);               
                _recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
                _recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.HeAac);
                _recorder.SetAudioChannels(1);
                _recorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                _recorder.SetAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
                _recorder.SetOutputFile(MediaPath.tempDir + Java.IO.File.Separator + File_Name);
```